# Reactjs - SassError: argument `$color` of `red($color)` must be a color

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-sass

After upgrading `node-saas`, I faced following error,

```
Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR in ./src/assets/scss/themes.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].oneOf[7].use[4]!./src/assets/scss/themes.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: argument `$color` of `red($color)` must be a color
        on line 37 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss, in function `red`
        from line 37 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss, in function `to-rgb`
        from line 83 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_root.scss
        from line 15 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss
        from line 15 of src/assets/scss/config/default/bootstrap.scss
        from line 2 of src/assets/scss/themes.scss
>>   @return red($value), green($value), blue($value);

   ----------^
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: What's the value of `$color`? Please show the SCSS you're compiling.

Comment: I am also having this issue, I can't work out if it is bootstrap, the webpack config or scss....